# count floating object that pass through the height of canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

i have a headache over this code. i trying to search for help but none :(

i want to count object that pass through the height of canvas and if more than 5 it will count as game over.

i'm a newbie so sorry if the coding is so miserable. I try to do this in the animate function:

```
if (object.y<0){
   gameOver();
}
```

but it just become 5 score or whatever scores then bring me to game over. This is the full code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:PeggyFont;
    font-size:20px;
    background-image:url('back.jpg');
}
h1 {
    font-size:50px;
}
canvas {
    border:5px solid #c3c3c3;
    position:absolute;
    top:120px;
    left:70px;
}
#canvas{
    z-index:1;
}
#canvas2{
    z-index:0;
    display:none;
}
#splash{
    z-index:2;
}
#gameover{
    z-index:3;
}
#score {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top:130px;
    left:490px;
    color:#087276;
    z-index:4;
}
#timerDisplay {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:150px;
    left:490px;
    color:#087276;
    z-index:5;
}
#howto {
    margin-left:700px;
    margin-right:70px;
    font-size:30px;
}
</style>
<title>Bubble Pop</title>
<body>
<div id="back">
<h1>Bubble Pop Game</h1>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<center>
<canvas id="canvas" height= "500" width="500">
</canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" height= "500" width="500">
</canvas>
<canvas id="splash" height= "500" width="500">
</canvas>
<canvas id="gameover" height= "500" width="500">
</canvas>
<p id="score" >Score: 0</p>
<p id="timerDisplay"></p>
<div id="howto">
Pop the bubble as many as you can within 1 minute!! The <font   style="color:blue">BLUE</font> one
has scored 2 and the <font style="color:red">RED</font> one has scored 1.<br>
Good Luck!
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
</center>
</div>
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#splash").show();
    $("#canvas").hide();
    $("#gameover").hide();
    $("#score").hide();
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var splash = document.getElementById("splash");
    var s = splash.getContext("2d");
    var gameover = document.getElementById("gameover");
    var gm = gameover.getContext("2d");
    var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    var c2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
    var splashOffset=$("#splash").offset();
    var gmOffset=$("#gameover").offset();
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left+70;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top+120;
    var splashoffsetX = splashOffset.left;
    var splashoffsetY = splashOffset.top;
    var gmoffsetX = gmOffset.left+70;
    var gmoffsetY = gmOffset.top+120;
    var $score = $("#score");
    var $timerDisplay = $("#timerDisplay");
    var j = 0;
    var k = 0;
    //var active = true;
    var active = false;
    var spawnLineY = 500;
    var spawnLineYtop = 0;
    var spawnRate = 900;
    var spawnRateOfDescent = 3;
    var lastSpawn = -1;
    var objects=[];
    var rects=[];
    var rects2=[];
    var startTime = Date.now();
    var g = s.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,500);
    var g2 = gm.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,500);
    var g3 = c2.createLinearGradient(0,0,0,500);
    var image= new Image();
    var image2= new Image();
    var image3= new Image();
    var image4= new Image();
    var image5= new Image();
    var image6= new Image();
    var sound = new Audio();
    var sound2 = new Audio();
    sound.src = "backgame.ogg";
    sound2.src = "collision2.wav";
    //animate();

    function spawnRandomObject(){
        var t;
        if (Math.random()<0.50){
            t = "red";
        } else {
            t = "blue";
        }
        var object={
            type:t,
            x:Math.random()*(canvas.width-40)+20,
            y:spawnLineY,
            radius:20
        }
        objects.push(object);
    }

    function animate(){
        //active=true;
        sound.play();
        var time=Date.now();
        if(time>(lastSpawn+spawnRate)){
            lastSpawn = time;
            spawnRandomObject();
        }
        if (active){
        webkitRequestAnimationFrame(animate);
        }
        c.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        //c.beginPath();
        //c.moveTo(0,spawnLineY);
        //c.lineTo(canvas.width,spawnLineY);
        //c.stroke();
        //c.beginPath();
        //c.moveTo(0,spawnLineYtop);
        //c.lineTo(canvas.width,spawnLineYtop);
        //c.stroke();
        var timeElapsed = startTime - Date.now() + 61000;
        if (timeElapsed < 1000) {
            gameOver();
        }
        var timeElapsed_second = Math.floor(timeElapsed/1000);
        $timerDisplay.text("Time: "+timeElapsed_second);

        for (var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
            var object = objects[i];
            object.y=object.y-spawnRateOfDescent;
            c.beginPath();
            c.arc(object.x,object.y,object.radius,0,Math.PI*2);
            c.closePath();
            c.fillStyle=object.type;
            c.fill();

            //NOT WORKING
            if (object.y<0){
                                gameOver();
                           }
        }
    }

    function handleButtonClick(e){
        canvasMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
        canvasMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
        for(var i=0;i<objects.length;i++){
            var dx = parseInt(canvasMouseX-objects[i].x);
            var dy = parseInt(canvasMouseY-objects[i].y);
            var asd = dx*dx+dy*dy;
            var hit = (dx*dx+dy*dy)<(objects[i].radius*objects[i].radius);
            if (hit){
                if (objects[i].type=="red"){
                    sound2.play();
                    j=j+1;
                    objects[i].x=objects[i].x+1000;
                }
                else {
                    sound2.play();
                    j=j+2;
                    objects[i].x=objects[i].x+1000;
                }
            }
            $score.text("Score: "+j);
        }
    }

    function gameOver(){
        sound.pause();
        active = false;
        $("#gameover").show();
        $("#canvas").hide();
    }
    $("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleButtonClick(e);});

    g3.addColorStop(0,"#04a0b7");
    g3.addColorStop(.3,"#04bfdb");
    g3.addColorStop(.7,"#5beaff");
    g3.addColorStop(1,"#cef9ff");

    c2.fillStyle=g3;
    c2.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    c2.beginPath();
    image5.onload = function(){
        c2.drawImage(image5, 0, 0, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 200, 0, 125, 82);
        c2.drawImage(image5, 390, 0, 125, 82);
        c2.drawImage(image5, -50, 200, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 150, 200, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 350, 200, 125, 82);
        c2.drawImage(image5, 0, 400, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 200, 400, 125, 82);
        c2.drawImage(image5, 400, 400, 125, 82);
    }
    image6.onload = function(){
        //s.drawImage(image2, -100, 100, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 100, 100, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 300, 100, 125, 82);
        c2.drawImage(image6, 320, 300, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 100, 300, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, -100, 300, 125, 82);
    }
    image5.src='awan.png';
    image6.src='awan2.png';

    g.addColorStop(0,"#04a0b7");
    g.addColorStop(.3,"#04bfdb");
    g.addColorStop(.7,"#5beaff");
    g.addColorStop(1,"#cef9ff");

    s.fillStyle=g;
    s.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    s.beginPath();
    image.onload = function(){
        s.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 200, 0, 125, 82);
        s.drawImage(image, 390, 0, 125, 82);
        s.drawImage(image, -50, 200, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 150, 200, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 350, 200, 125, 82);
        s.drawImage(image, 0, 400, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 200, 400, 125, 82);
        s.drawImage(image, 400, 400, 125, 82);
    }
    image2.onload = function(){
        //s.drawImage(image2, -100, 100, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 100, 100, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 300, 100, 125, 82);
        s.drawImage(image2, 320, 300, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 100, 300, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, -100, 300, 125, 82);
    }
    image.src='awan.png';
    image2.src='awan2.png';

    s.font="70px PeggyFont";
    s.fillStyle ="#087276";
    s.fillText("Bubble Pop",100,170);

    var rect={
        x:200,
        y:300,
    }
    rects.push(rect);

    for (var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
        var rect = rects[i];
        s.beginPath();
        s.fillRect(rect.x,rect.y,100,50);
        s.fillStyle="#087276";
        s.font = '25pt PeggyFont';
        s.fillStyle ="#20d7b7";
        s.fillText ('Play', 220, 338);
    }

    function Play(e){
        splashMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-splashoffsetX);
        splashMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-splashoffsetY);
        for(var i=0;i<rects.length;i++){
            var dx = parseInt(splashMouseX-rects[i].x);
            var dy = parseInt(splashMouseY-rects[i].y);
            if (dx>0&&dx<100&&dy>0&&dy<50){
                $("#splash").hide();
                $("#canvas").show();
                $("#canvas2").show();
                active = true;
                $("#timerDisplay").show();
                $("#score").show();
                $("#miss").show();
                animate();
            }
        }
    }
    $("#splash").mousedown(function(e){Play(e);});

    g2.addColorStop(0,"#04a0b7");
    g2.addColorStop(.3,"#04bfdb");
    g2.addColorStop(.7,"#5beaff");
    g2.addColorStop(1,"#cef9ff");

    gm.fillStyle=g2;
    gm.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    gm.beginPath();
    image3.onload = function(){
        gm.drawImage(image3, 0, 0, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 200, 0, 125, 82);
        gm.drawImage(image3, 390, 0, 125, 82);
        gm.drawImage(image3, -50, 200, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 150, 200, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 350, 200, 125, 82);
        gm.drawImage(image3, 0, 400, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image, 200, 400, 125, 82);
        gm.drawImage(image3, 400, 400, 125, 82);
    }
    image4.onload = function(){
        //s.drawImage(image2, -100, 100, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 100, 100, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 300, 100, 125, 82);
        gm.drawImage(image4, 320, 300, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, 100, 300, 125, 82);
        //s.drawImage(image2, -100, 300, 125, 82);
    }
    image3.src='awan.png';
    image4.src='awan2.png';

    gm.font="70px PeggyFont";
    gm.fillStyle ="#087276";
    gm.fillText("Game Over",90,170);

    var rect2={
        x:190,
        y:350,
    }
    rects2.push(rect2);

    for (var i=0;i<rects2.length;i++){
        gm.beginPath();
        gm.fillRect(rect2.x,rect2.y,120,50);
        gm.fillStyle="#087276";
        gm.font = '25pt PeggyFont';
        gm.fillStyle ="#20d7b7";
        gm.fillText ('Restart', 195, 388);
    }

    function Restart(e){
        gmMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-gmoffsetX);
        gmMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-gmoffsetY);
        for(var i=0;i<rects2.length;i++){
            var dx = parseInt(gmMouseX-rects2[i].x);
            var dy = parseInt(gmMouseY-rects2[i].y);
            if (dx>0&&dx<120&&dy>0&&dy<50){
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    }
    $("#gameover").click(function(e){Restart(e);});
});
</script>
</body>
```

JS Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/yt7Zn/

Comment: try put it on http://jsfiddle.net/ and post link too this helps people test your code.. Here http://jsfiddle.net/yt7Zn/  I seem to get Game Over even when Blue or Red ball didn't reach the very top.

Comment: I am not a game programmer, but the simplest idea could be that you could check the position of the object and each time it becomes equal to that particular height, you could increase the value of a variable (that is for this sole purpose). When this variable becomes 5, its game over. This is how I would have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close!

Adjust like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/5zp4M/

- Add a `failCounter` that starts at 0 and increments to 5 with each new object failure (object.y<=0)
- When the `failCounter` is at 5 then declare gameOver();
- When a bubble floats above the canvas (object.y<0), turn it off so it won't continue to count as another failure in the next animation frame.  This is why you immediately get gameOver when any 1 bubble floats above the canvas--you're repeatedly failing the same bubble!
- Reset the failCounter if you restart a new game.

Example code using failCounter:

```
// set the failure counter to zero at the beginning of the game (or when restarting)

var failCounter=0;

// add a property to object that indicates if this object is still in play

var object={
    type:t,
    x:Math.random()*(canvas.width-40)+20,
    y:spawnLineY,
    radius:20,
    isInPlay:true,
}

// in the animation loop
// If the object is still in play (hasn't previously failed) and the object now fails
// then increment the failCounter and take this bubble out of play.
// If the failCounter reaches 5 then gameOver

if (object.isInPlay && object.y<0){
    object.isInPlay=false;
    if(++failCounter>=5){
        gameOver();
    }
}
```

Comment: i had try this but it always count to 5 when i play it, although it doesn't pass the top of canvas :(

Comment: weird, is it just me? i try it in my browser and not working. i try in fiddle and and can't play it. :(

Comment: I've tested in IE11, Chrome34 & FF and the game is triggering gameOver after 5 bubbles float up past the canvas.  I didn't check the logic of your gameplay--I only added the code necessary to count the floating bubbles (as you asked in your question).

Comment: if it is just counting 5 bubbles then that's really working. thanks btw.